# Android broadcast with custom permission

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver

I would like to send a broadcast form app A to app B and I would like to protect them with custom permission. I followed the guide from [Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#sending-broadcasts-permissions) but I get "permission denial" every time. (It works fine without permission or with a random system permission)

App A manifest:

```
<permission android:name="sendperm"/>
<uses-permission android:name="sendperm" />

<application
    ...
</application>
```

This is how I send the broadcast:

```
val intent = Intent("aaaaa")
intent.component = ComponentName("com.example.poc.cloudsyncreceiver", "com.example.poc.cloudsyncreceiver.CsReceiver")
sendBroadcast(intent, "sendperm")
```

App B manifest: (I can define the permission in both apps, because they use the same signature, so it's not an issue)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.poc.cloudsyncreceiver">

<permission android:name="sendperm"/>
<uses-permission android:name="sendperm" />

<application
    ...

    <receiver android:name=".CsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="aaaaa" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

App B receiver

```
class CsReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
    Log.d("xxxx", "onReceive: jeeee")
}
```

}

The error I got:

> W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=aaaaa flg=0x10 cmp=com.example.poc.cloudsyncreceiver/.CsReceiver } to com.example.poc.cloudsyncreceiver/.CsReceiver requires sendperm due to sender com.example.poc.cloudsyncbroadcaster (uid 10180)

Comment: FWIW, your error does not match your code, as you are not applying the permission anywhere -- there is no `android:permission="sendpermmmm"` on your `<receiver>`. Similarly, your error message refers to a different permission than does your code. Also, note that your permission is a `normal` permission, so anyone else can just add `<uses-permission android:name="sendperm" />` to get it. You may want a `signature` permission, so only apps signed by your signing key can hold it.

Comment: 1. You're right, I copied the wrong error message. I updated it.

Comment: 2. I don't need to put the permission tag to the receiver, this is two diffrenet things. See:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#sending-broadcasts-permissions

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts-permissions

But I tried it with the permission attribute as well and it still doesn't work.

Comment: "I don't need to put the permission tag to the receiver, this is two diffrenet things" -- to defend an activity, service, or receiver with a permission, you put `android:permission` on the component's element. This is covered by [the documentation that you linked to](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts-permissions).

Comment: Actually these are two links but stackoverflow formats it weirdly. So there are sender protection and receiver protection. I would like to implement the sender protection and android:permission required for the receiver protection. But again, I tried to implement receiver protection as well and both of them at the same time but none of them seems to work.

Comment: "I would like to implement the sender protection" -- ah! My apologies, I am far more used to receiver protection. In fact, I do not know if I have ever tried sender protection. With custom permissions, there used to be an order-of-installation problem, though that was fixed in Android 5.0 or 5.1 IIRC. Still, it might be worth an experiment to see if you get different results if you install App A before App B, compared to installing App B before App A.

Comment: Yes according to the documentation this still can be a problem. This is why I put the `<permission android:name="sendperm"/>` tag into both application.I tried different install orders as well, but with no results.